# Why did Yarn stop working all of a sudden?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, yarnpkg, oh-my-zsh

I have a React & Node app on a MacBook Pro M1 chip, and we use Yarn to download all the needed packages and dependencies.

Initially, when I ran the `yarn` command, everything worked fine, but all of a sudden, I got the following error:
`error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/object.assign/-/object.assign-4.1.4.tgz: incorrect data check".`

I spent quite some time researching this issue, and what I found was to try the following:

- Run `yarn set strict-ssl false` (didn't work, same error)
- Re-cloning the repo (didn't work, same error)
- Updated macOS (didn't work, same error)
- Restarting the computer multiple times (didn't work, same error)
- Running the `yarn`, `yarn install`, & `npm install` commands with & without the company's VPN connected (didn't work, same error)
- Restarting my modem (didn't work, same error)
- Connecting an ethernet cable to the computer (didn't work, same error)
- Re-installing Xcode (didn't work, same error)

The last thing I thought of doing is restoring the computer to the factory settings, but given that there are pre-installed security policies and applications, I can't do that

I was wondering if someone had an idea of why this is happening & how I can fix it or shed some light on the matter.

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

This started happening after I installed `oh-my-zsh` with the `powerlevel10k` theme. I don't think that this is a problem. Nevertheless, for good measure, I un-installed it and reset everything to its defaults, but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem either

Comment: What you can try to do is remove it from your package.json and wget the file and unzip it and add it to your node_modules folder manually. I was able to unzip is successfully on macos.

Comment: Also, what node version are you using? You may need to look into Rosetta 2 if you're using an old node version

Comment: @Ayudh I am using Nove v14.18.3. The issue is not with the actual package itself per say. I downloaded the package manually and tried it again, and it gave me an issue with another package. Also, the node_modules folder doesn't get created because it is not passing this step

Comment: can you try a new node version?